# Images blurring after placing in a Photoshop template

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, resolution

I created a new file in Photoshop. This file will serve as a template for my Facebook posts. 
I then opened an image in Photoshop (size - 377KB; 1024x683). This image is quite sharp & clear as it is. But once I drag & dropped this image in to the Photoshop template, it lost all its clarity & now appears really blurred.

I feel this has something to do with my Photoshop settings but am really not sure. I am using Adobe Photoshop CC 2014.

I've also tried with multiple images and this blurring issue always crops up.

These are my template image settings:

[image: New image setting in photoshop]

This is the original image:

[image: Original image]

This is my image after attempting to edit it in Photoshop:

[image: Edited image]

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE! Your image looks fairly ok to me. It could be that your resolution is really low and you are zoomed too far in?

Comment: Hi Heena, you'll need to give us some more to go on here. What size and resolution is the new document and the original image? A screenshot of the original as well as the edited image would help too (we've got nothing to compare it too!)

Comment: Thanks Cai & Scott, I have now edited my question. Your help will be really appreciated. Thanks again!

Comment: Are the images "blurry" if you just open them? *"I drag & dropped this image in the photoshop template"* -- that kind of eludes to the template being a higher resolution than the image perhaps. Are those settings above for the image or for your template?

Comment: The image is ok when i open them in photoshop. The problem arises only when i drop them in this new template I have created. The settings screenshot attached above is of the template I have created and not the original image.

Comment: Okay, your template is only at 72ppi.. is that intentional? A lower PPI is going to cause the image quality to possibly degrade.

Comment: Anh, I didn't know what I should be setting it at. Am new to photoshop and finding my way around. What ppi would you recommend? I'll be using this template for social media purposes. Thanks!

Comment: I had Cai's comment which just deleted itself or something :-/

Comment: Well there's more information needed... what's the template for? What's the intended output? 72ppi *might* be fine for some uses, it would be terribly low for other uses.

Comment: It's for social media usage; primarily Facebook & Instagram - the ideal size for which i understand is 500x500px. Thanks again :-)

Comment: @Heena 500x500 is too small for social media images (without checking that is probably the *minimum* size), I usually make social media images around 1600x1600, or 1200x1200 minimum.

Comment: This is of great help to me! I have increased the size of the image and changed the ppi from 72 to 300. Thanks Scott & Cai! Really appreciate your help :-)

Answer (score 5):

Your template is 500 × 500 pixels (as seen in the Image Size dialog). Your original image is 1024 × 683 pixels. You're reducing the original to roughly 500 × 430 pixels. The loss of quality in this case is pretty much expected.

The only real solution is not to reduce the pixel size of your image. You'd be much better off leaving the image at its original size and simply cropping in one direction (rather than cropping *and* resizing).

If you do need to reduce (or enlarge) the pixel size of your image then do so as little as possible and try resampling with different interpolation methods:

[image]

This may be of use:

- [**Photoshop image size and resolution - Adobe Support**](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/image-size-resolution.html)

A few notes on social media...

If you’re using this template for social media images then 500 × 500 pixels is probably too small. I’m not sure what the recommended sizes are these days but I usually (depending on the specific usage) make social media images around 1600 × 1600 pixels (keep in mind that only pixel sizes matter on screens, PPI is mostly irrelevant).

One thing to keep in mind is that Facebook and the like will actually further compress your images so you may see a drop in quality *after* uploading them due to that. The advice given is usually to keep the file size below 100 kb or use a PNG which may or may not prevent the images being compressed.

- [**Facebook Help Centre - How can I make sure that my photos display in the highest possible quality?**](https://www.facebook.com/help/266520536764594)

Answer (score -2):

Here's a work-around, since PS is a little special in this regard.  Right click your photo and figure out its dimensions (on a mac, right click and select 'get-info).

Then create a new file w/ the photos dimensions (e.g., 6000x4000).  Drag and drop your imagine into this new file.  Now take this layer w/ your photo on it and drag it to whatever other photoshop file you have opened.

Problem solved.

(You obviously will have to resize your photo layer once it's in the new file b/c it will be HUGE).

yes.  photoshop is stupid.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. What you're describing can be achieved with turning off `Resize Image During Place` option in PS Preferences.